# Visual Studio - new "default" property values for inherited controls

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm looking for help setting a new default property value for an inherited control in Visual Studio:

```
class NewCombo : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
  public NewCombo() { DropDownItems = 50; }
}
```

The problem is that the base class property `DropDownItems` has a 'default' attribute set on it that is a different value (not 50).  As a result, when I drag the control onto a form, the designer file gets an explicit `mycontrol.DropDownItems = 50;` line.

At first, this doesn't matter.  But if later I change my inherited class to `DropDownItems = 45;` in the constructor, this does not affect any of the controls on any form since all those designer files still have the value 50 hard-coded in them.  And the whole point was to have the value set in one place so I can deal with the customer changing his mind.

Obviously, if I were creating my own custom property in the subclass, I could give it its own designer default attribute of whatever I wanted.  But here I'm wanting to change the default values of properties in the base.  Is there any way to apply Visual Studio attributes to a base class member?  Or is there some other workaround to get the result I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your derived class you need to either override (or shadow using *new*) the property in question and then re-apply the default value attribute.